# SQL SELECT QUERY BY DATE

Tags: mysql, date

I have two related tables with many records based on dates.
I need to select ONLY the valid rate based on a certain date.

These are an example of data:

on HEADERTABLE...

```
 ID, PICKUP, DELIVERY, VALIDFROM, VALIDTO, COMMODITY, CARRIER
1, NEW YORK, CHICAGO, 01-OCT-13,31-OCT-13, FOOTWEAR, DHL
2, NEW YORK, CHICAGO, 20-OCT-13,31-OCT-13, FOOTWEAR, UPS
3, NEW YORK, CHICAGO, 30-OCT-13,31-OCT-13, FOOTWEAR, DHL
4, NEW YORK, CHICAGO, 30-OCT-13,31-OCT-13, WOODEN PRODUCTS, DHL
```

on linestable:

```
ID, HEADERTABLEID, RATEDESC, RATE
2325, 1, DELIVERY, 1000
2354, 2, DELIVERY, 1500
2355, 2, TAX, 100
2355, 3, DELIVERY, 1200
2356, 3, TAX, 110
2380, 4, DELIVERY, 1000
```

So by using a certain date (thedate variable below), I need to display ONLY one option. For example, if thedate=25-oct-13, then the record to be shown is Id 2 (from headertable + linked rates in linestable)

If thedate=10-oct-13, then option 1 is the one to be shown.

if thedate=30-oct-13, then 2 records (Id 3 and 4) will be displayed (difference is the COMMODITY)

This is the code I am using (I've tried many others, with no luck) but obviously there is something missing as it displays all records.

Any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT  * from schema1.headertable, schema1.linestable
WHERE headertable.Id= linestable.headertableId
AND headertable.Validfrom <= STR_TO_DATE('" & thedate & "','%Y-%m-%d')
AND headertable.Validto >= STR_TO_DATE('" & thedate & "','%Y-%m-%d')
AND headertable.PICKUP LIKE '%NEW YORK%'
AND headertable.DELIVERY LIKE '%CHICAGO%'
ORDER BY headertable.Validfrom DESC, linestable.Id DESC
```

Comment: You have two records in HEADERTABLE that differ only by `VALIDFROM`. You haven't stated this clearly, but it looks like you want to retrieve the  record with the *most recent* `VALIDFROM` date that's on or before `thedate`.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I might not have explained myself properly, I have amended the question to include a carrier.
The thedate MUST be between the validfrom and validto always, not on or before.

Answer (score 1):

To return only the first record from a resultset, append`LIMIT 1` to the end of the query.

Comment: thanks. Almost worked but it only returns one record (Id 2 on headertable is linked to 2 rows in linestable,and both should be displayed, but only shows 1.

Answer (score 1):

OK, let's work this problem out in a structured way, in concert with the idea that we're using **Structured** Query Language.

First, we need to grab the lines from your `headertable` that match your date. This query here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dff43/4/0 picks out the matching rows in `headertable`.  There are two of these rows.

```
SELECT headertable.*
  FROM ( SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2013-10-25', '%Y-%m-%d') AS thedate) d
  JOIN headertable
 WHERE headertable.Validfrom <= thedate
   AND headertable.Validto   >= thedate
   AND headertable.PICKUP LIKE '%NEW YORK%'
   AND headertable.DELIVERY LIKE '%CHICAGO%'
```

Notice the little trick with `SELECT STR_TO_DATE(...`.  This lets us put the `thedate` parameter into the query just once, and use it multiple times.

But your specification calls for just one of these rows, not two. We have to disambiguate the two, by picking the matching one with the *latest* `Validfrom` date.

Let's try this to find the `Validfrom` date of the correct row. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dff43/6/0 This gives back Oct 20.

```
SELECT MAX(Validfrom) AS Validfrom
  FROM ( SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2013-10-25', '%Y-%m-%d') AS thedate) d
  JOIN headertable
 WHERE headertable.Validfrom <= thedate
   AND headertable.Validto   >= thedate
   AND headertable.PICKUP LIKE '%NEW YORK%'
   AND headertable.DELIVERY LIKE '%CHICAGO%'
```

So, now we have to find the single row that gives the "best" match, using this date.  Here's how to do this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dff43/14/0

```
SELECT headertable.*
  FROM ( 
        SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2013-10-25', '%Y-%m-%d') AS thedate,
               '%NEW YORK%' AS PICKUP,
               '%CHICAGO%'  AS DELIVERY
       ) AS d
   JOIN headertable
  WHERE Validfrom <= thedate
    AND Validto   >= thedate
    AND PICKUP LIKE d.PICKUP
    AND DELIVERY LIKE d.DELIVERY
    AND ValidFrom IN  /* disambiguate */
      (
        SELECT MAX(Validfrom) AS Validfrom
          FROM headertable
         WHERE Validfrom <= thedate
           AND Validto   >= thedate
           AND PICKUP LIKE d.PICKUP
           AND DELIVERY LIKE d.DELIVERY
       )
```

This query is a bit of a hairball. But so are your business rules here.

Finally, we have to join to your other table. That's pretty easy compared to your date selection logic. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dff43/17/0  We'll use `JOIN` syntax instead of your comma syntax because it makes the query logic clearer.

```
SELECT headertable.*, linestable.*
  FROM ( 
        SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2013-10-25', '%Y-%m-%d') AS thedate,
               '%NEW YORK%' AS PICKUP,
               '%CHICAGO%'  AS DELIVERY
       ) AS d
   JOIN headertable
   JOIN linestable ON headertable.Id = linestable.headertableId
  WHERE Validto   >= thedate
    AND headertable.PICKUP LIKE d.PICKUP
    AND headertable.DELIVERY LIKE d.DELIVERY
    AND ValidFrom IN
      (
        SELECT MAX(Validfrom) AS Validfrom
          FROM headertable
         WHERE Validfrom <= thedate
           AND Validto   >= thedate
           AND PICKUP LIKE d.PICKUP
           AND DELIVERY LIKE d.DELIVERY
       )
```

This also seems to work for your 30-oct-2013 date.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dff43/19/0

Note: I believe this date ambiguity reveals a problem with your business rules.  It seems to me that your ValidFrom and ValidTo dates should probably not overlap.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your detailed answer. I have spent several hours to make it work but I was unable to do so. In your link to sqlfiddle.co, if you put date 2013-10-20, you'll see you only get UPS, when in fact both DHL and UPS should be shown, as they are two different companies, both with valid rates on that date.
Nevertheless I will continue to work with your code as it is going on the direction I am after.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT  * from schema1.headertable, schema1.linestable
WHERE headertable.Id= linestable.headertableId
AND STR_TO_DATE('" & thedate & "','%Y-%m-%d') between headertable.Validfrom and DATE_ADD(headertable.Validto, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND headertable.PICKUP LIKE '%NEW YORK%'
AND headertable.DELIVERY LIKE '%CHICAGO%'
ORDER BY headertable.Validfrom DESC, linestable.Id DESC
```

also make sure the data type is right: Validfrom and ValidTo should be date; thedate should be in Y-m-d format, eg. 2013-10-14

Comment: thanks, unfortunately your code returns all rates from 01-oct-13 to 20-oct-13 (if thedate=20-oct-13 for example, it returns 01-oct and 20-oct, id 1 and 2)
Yes, thedate is on Y-m-d format

Comment: yes, thats because the date given 20-oct-13 is in the range of id 1 and 2. you need to either edit the to date so there is no overlapping or limit the result numbers to 1 by adding 'limit 1' and the end of the query

Comment: thanks, the idea is that it shows only the latest record based on the validfrom date. Adding LIMIT 1 works, but only shows one record from the linestable, but in many cases there are 2-10 matching rows in linestable which are linked to 1 record in headertable.